# Adjoint (or transpose) of the Radon transform in scikit-image

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement an optimization algorithm in Python for solving a computerized tomography problem with TV regularization. I know I can use the function "radon" from scikit-image, but the point it that I also need the transpose (or adjoint operator) of the Radon transform as well.

Does anyone know if there is a way to compute the transpose matrix of the Radon Transform in scikit-image?

Comment: This is a software question, not a mathematics question. You might get an answer but in general you should direct it to the right forum for an answer.

Comment: I see you've [already posted elsewhere on the web](https://forum.image.sc/t/adjoint-or-transpose-of-the-radon-transform-in-scikit-image/63589) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220104/adjoint-or-transpose-of-the-radon-transform-in-scikit-image).  I know you're probably eager for an answer but nobody likes excessive crossposting.

Comment: [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscikit-learn%5D+transpose) `[scikit-learn]` at stackoverflow transpose gets over 200 hits... any of those happen to have the solution?  searching with `scikit-image` gets fewer hits, but you might check that too.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help and time. As you can see I'm new here (and in the other forums you pointed)... I promisse I'll be more carefull next time here (if any). Bye!

Answer (score 0):

By reading the documentation, I don't think that Scikit Radon transform has this feature. I would therefore not use it on my own, since the adjoint is the most needed operation in scientific computing. Browsing through the web, I saw at least one library (pylops) offering this feature:
https://pylops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plot_radon.html

The other option is to reprogram it as a sparse matrix and use standard matrix-vector products...

Comment: You got exactly the point: I have a sort of primal-dual method, so the adjoint is really crucial. pylops looks really interesting, I will take a look at it. Many thanks for you kind reply!